# Content type field with term reference or users

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax

I have "People" content type that has some fields; one of those is "field1," which is a term reference, and uses an autocomplete widget.

How can I display only "Users" registered with particular roles in the term reference with the autocomplete?

I need to display it on http://example.com/sitename/admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

[image: screenshot]

I am displaying any view or content here; this is where administrator users add the fields to the user accounts and in the "field1". How can I display or list only ["username" with respective to "roles"] or ["username"]?

Answer (score 1):

If you install [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), you should be able to use a view to determine which content/terms/etc. are shown. These settings appear on the field settings page for the Term Reference.